# What is exactly mean by " where(n) " in mysql query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have seen a query to find nth highest salary in table as;

```
SELECT *
FROM one one1
WHERE ( n ) = ( SELECT COUNT( one2.salary )
                FROM one one2
                WHERE one2.salary >= one1.salary
              )
```

Can explain how is this will work? What is mean by `"WHERE(n)"` here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is called [row constructor](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/row-subqueries.html).

For your case (`scalar subquery`) brackets are redundant, and you can use just:

```
SELECT *
FROM one one1
WHERE  n  = ( SELECT COUNT( one2.salary )
               FROM one one2
               WHERE one2.salary >= one1.salary
             )
```

But it is useful when you need to compare more than one value:

```
SELECT *
FROM t1
WHERE (col1,col2) = (SELECT col3, col4 FROM t2 WHERE id = 10);
```

Comment: @Shivinnarayan This is correlated scalar subquery, for each record from table it counts salaries which are higher than current salary in outer table. Then it does comparison with n so you will get ranking

Answer (score 1):

When writing a query, it is useful to use table aliases for all columns:

```
SELECT one1.*
FROM one one1
WHERE 2 = (SELECT COUNT( one2.salary )
           FROM one one2
           WHERE one2.salary >= one1.salary
          );
```

What is this doing?  For each row in `one1`, the subquery is counting the number of rows that have a salary as large or larger than that row.

For the row(s) that have the largest salary, the count returned by the subquery is the number of rows with the maximum.  If we assume that the salary values are different, then this provides the ranking.  When the value is 2, then we get the second largest.

However, you might not get a value of "2" -- for instance, if three rows are tied for the maximum.  Then the value will be "3" for the top salary.  You might want "1" for this, so a better construct is:

However, that assumption is not always true.  So, a better way to write this construct is:

```
SELECT one1.*
FROM one one1
WHERE 2 = (SELECT 1 + COUNT( one2.salary )
           FROM one one2
           WHERE one2.salary > one1.salary
          );
```

The above is equivalent to the ANSI standard `rank()` function.  Often, you really want to know the second highest *different* salary (ignoring ties).  This is the ANSI standard `dense_rank()` function, and is implemented using:

```
SELECT one1.*
FROM one one1
WHERE 2 = (SELECT 1 + COUNT(DISTINCT one2.salary )
           FROM one one2
           WHERE one2.salary > one1.salary
          );
```

Answer (score 0):

But it is useful when you need to compare more than one value:

SELECT *
FROM t1
WHERE (col1,col2) = (SELECT col3, col4 FROM t2 WHERE id = 10);